# Solving an ODE and a PDE

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, finite-element-method

I am trying to solve coupled sets of (partial) differential equations. For my ODE, I use

```
ti = 0;
tf = 5;
ri = 0;
rf = 1.5;
ai = 0;
af = 2;
sol[t_, x_, y_, z_, 
    a_] = {X[t, x, y, z, a], Y[t, x, y, z, a], Z[t, x, y, z, a]} /. 
    First[NDSolve[{ D[X[t, x, y, z, a], t] == Y[t, x, y, z, a] ,
        D[Y[t, x, y, z, a], t] == Z[t, x, y, z, a]  + 3.5 t, 
        D[Z[t, x, y, z, a], t] == X[t, x, y, z, a] + 2 Sin[a t] , 
       X[0, x, y, z, a] == Sin[x + y], 
       Y[0, x, y, z, a] == Sin[2 z + y], 
       Z[0, x, y, z, a] == Sin[x + 0.5 z]}, {X, Y, Z}, {t, ti, 
       tf}, {x, ri, rf}, {y, ri, rf}, {z, ri, rf}, {a, ai, af}, 
      MaxSteps -> \[Infinity]]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

This solves these equations. Here my question is how to put `{x,y,z}`, which are at the moment inside a cube, inside a particular manifold,e.q, inside a sphere with radius `rf`.

For `{X,Y,Z}`, I also should solve another set of partial differential equations. Here I implemented

```
sol[t_, x_, y_, z_, 
    a_] = {X[t, x, y, z, a], Y[t, x, y, z, a], Z[t, x, y, z, a]} /. 
    First[
     NDSolve[{ 
       D[X[t, x, y, z, a], t] == 
        Y[t, x, y, z, a] + D[Z[t, x, y, z, a], y] + 0.5 t ,
        D[Y[t, x, y, z, a], t] == 
        Z[t, x, y, z, a] + D[X[t, x, y, z, a], z] , 
        D[Z[t, x, y, z, a], t] == 
        X[t, x, y, z, a] + D[Y[t, x, y, z, a], x] + 2 Sin[a t] , 
       X[0, x, y, z, a] == Cos[a x + y], 
       Y[0, x, y, z, a] == Sin[z + y], 
       Z[0, x, y, z, a] == a Sin[x + z]}, {X, Y, Z}, {t, ti, tf}, {x, 
       ri, rf}, {y, ri, rf}, {z, ri, rf}, {a, ai, af}, 
      MaxSteps -> \[Infinity], 
      Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t, 
        "SpatialDiscretization" -> 
         "FiniteElement"}]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

But this script is not fully correct as I get these errors [image]

Do you have suggestions for resolving these issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The finite element method in Version 13.2 is available for 1D/1.5D/2D/2.5D and 3D plus time. Your problem is 4D plus time. For this use the tensor product grid method - like in your first example.

Comment: (+1)Thanks! Replacing `FiniteElement` with `TensorProductGrid` solves the second problem. Do you have a suggestion for the first question as well?

Comment: @Shasa If you are thinking in terms of `Element[ {x,y,z,a}, Ball[]]`, then no, the tensor product grid method is for rectangular domains.

Comment: I see! Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 2):

I am note sure if I understand this correctly: " how to put {x,y,z}, which are at the moment inside a cube". I assume you want to display the vector field inside a cube. The vector field may e.g. be displayed using SliceVectorPlot3D. But besides x,y,z you have 2 more variables t and a. This may be handled using "Manipulate" (note the plot is rather slow):

```
ti = 0; tf = 5; ri = 0; rf = 1.5; ai = 0; af = 2;
sol[t_, x_, y_, z_, 
   a_] = {X[t, x, y, z, a], Y[t, x, y, z, a], Z[t, x, y, z, a]} /. 
   First[NDSolve[{D[X[t, x, y, z, a], t] == Y[t, x, y, z, a], 
      D[Y[t, x, y, z, a], t] == Z[t, x, y, z, a] + 3.5 t, 
      D[Z[t, x, y, z, a], t] == X[t, x, y, z, a] + 2 Sin[a t], 
      X[0, x, y, z, a] == Sin[x + y], 
      Y[0, x, y, z, a] == Sin[2 z + y], 
      Z[0, x, y, z, a] == Sin[x + 0.5 z]}, {X, Y, Z}, {t, ti, tf}, {x,
       ri, rf}, {y, ri, rf}, {z, ri, rf}, {a, ai, af}, 
     MaxSteps -> \[Infinity]]];
Manipulate[
 SliceVectorPlot3D[
  sol[0, x, y, z, 0], {x, ri, rf}, {y, ri, rf}, {z, ri, rf}, 
  PlotLabel -> {t, a}]
 , {t, ti, tf}, {a, ai, af}]
```

[image]

For a slices sphere, you may write:

```
Manipulate[
 SliceVectorPlot3D[sol[0, x, y, z, 0], 
  "CenterCutSphere", {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
  PlotLabel -> {t, a}], {t, ti, tf}, {a, ai, af}]
```

[image]

For additional possibilities, look at the help.

Comment: In my examples, I used `{x, ri, rf}, {y, ri, rf}, {z, ri, rf}`, but in my first part of the question I was wondering about having sth like `{x,y,z} \[Element] sphere`? How to implement `sphere` or another manifold?

Comment: Look what I added.

Comment: (+1) Thank you for your effort. The answer of @user21 addresses my concern.